# Variables inside a function

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables

I have a div which acts like a button when I press it. I add classes to change color and the circle inside moves to the right when is clicked. What I would like to do, is to call a function and then change a global variable inside the function and pass it back. I am also testing the code using the document.getElementById("test").innerHTML and the 12th changes to 13th and vise versa successfully. However, the variable flag13th does not change. It always has a false value.

Any ideas folks on this? I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

```js
document.getElementById("toggleButton").addEventListener("click", dekatosTritos);

var flag13th = false;

function dekatosTritos() {
  var ThirteenthSalary = document.getElementById("toggleButton").classList;
  if ((ThirteenthSalary.contains("toggle-btn")) && (ThirteenthSalary.contains("active"))) {
    flag13th = false;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "12th";
  } else {
    flag13th = true;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "13th";
  }

}

document.getElementById("test11").innerHTML = flag13th;
```

```css
.toggle-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 28px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.toggle-btn .inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 80%;
}

.toggle-btn.active {
  background: #4F94CD;
}

.toggle-btn.active>.inner-circle {
  margin-left: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Question_13th">13th Month Salary</div>
<div id="toggleButton" class="toggle-btn">
  <div class="inner-circle"></div>
</div>
<p id="test">12th</p>
<p id="test11"> </p>
```

Comment: "However, the variable flag13th does not change. It always has a false value." — What makes you think that? You copy its value to test11's innerHTML when the document loads but after that you treat it as write only. How do you know it doesn't change if you never read it?

Comment: They shouldn't be the same. The test changes successfully whenever I press the div button. However this not the case with the test11 and thus flag13th...

Comment: @AndreasAlexandrou — You're repeating your assertion that the variable isn't changing, but there's still no evidence that you are right about that.

Comment: @Quentin thank you very much for the answer. You have absolute right. If I insert the code document.getElementById("test11").innerHTML=flag13th; inside if and else then it changes. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example that uses no JavaScript, but rather an `input` type **checkbox** that can be submitted with your form:

```css
.toggler {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggler-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: gray;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.toggler-btn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.toggler-label::after {
  content: attr(data-label);
}

/* CHECKED STATES */

.toggler:checked ~ .toggler-btn {
  background: #0bf;
}

.toggler:checked ~ .toggler-btn:after {
  transform: translateX(30px);
}

.toggler:checked ~ .toggler-label::after {
  content: attr(data-labelchecked);
}
```

```html
<div class="Question_13th">13th Month Salary?</div>

<input class="toggler" type="checkbox" id="13th" name="13th">
<label class="toggler-btn" for="13th"></label>
<div class="toggler-label" data-label="12th" data-labelchecked="13th"></div>
```

---

Here's an example that uses JavaScript, `classList.toggle()` and `bool = !bool` to toggle a boolean

```js
const EL_btn = document.querySelector("#toggleButton");
const EL_test = document.querySelector("#test");
let is13 = false;

function dekatosTritos() {
  is13 = !is13;  // Toggle boolean
  EL_btn.classList.toggle('active', is13);
  EL_test.innerHTML = is13 ? "13th" : "12th";
}

EL_btn.addEventListener("click", dekatosTritos); // Do on btn click
dekatosTritos();                                 // and on init.
```

```css
.toggle-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 28px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.toggle-btn.active {
  background: #4F94CD;
}

.toggle-btn .inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 80%;
}

.toggle-btn.active>.inner-circle {
  margin-left: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Question_13th">13th Month Salary</div>
<div id="toggleButton" class="toggle-btn">
  <div class="inner-circle"></div>
</div>
<p id="test"></p>
```

---